# Регулярное выражение для получения тегов из строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java, hashtag

Есть строка `#tag1#tag2#tag3`. Какое регулярное выражение мне использовать в яве что бы получить каждый тег?

Comment: Регулярность подобных вопросов о регулярных выражениях наводит на мысль о том что регеспы это зло...

Comment: Barmaley ♦, Регулярность подобных вопросов о регулярных выражениях скорее наводит на мысль о том что многие, почему-то, не хотят учить регулярные выражения ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String testStr = "#tag1#tag2#tag3";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(\\w)+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testStr);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(testStr.substring(m.start()+1, m.end()));
        }

    }
}
```

Как то так.

> Вывод:
>
> *tag1*
>
> *tag2*
>
> *tag3*

Comment: Держите плюсик, хоть и быдлокодие :)  
Выражение:  

    #(\\w+)
Результат:  

    match.group(1)

Comment: Да, затупил. Извиняюсь !
Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот это:

```
#([^#]+)
```

Это просто регулярка, с помощью которой можно получить список тегов. К сожалению не знаю какой класс нужно использовать в java.

Answer (score 0):

Есть строка, она может постоянно меняться, мне нужно из строки высунуть текст, пример:

```
CompaniesTemp.comp1.Branches.bra1.TransportObjects.kamaz
```

В этой строке мне нужно вытащить одно слова которое идет за `Branches`, а слово это `bra1`.
Пример 2:

```
CompaniesTemp.comp1.Branches.bra1.Departments.dep1.TransportObjects.132
```

С этой строки нужно вытащить два слова `bra1`, и `dep1` . Якоря у меня по которым идет ориентир `Branches` для  `bra1`, Departments для `dep1`. Пытался написать сам, но в регулярке неочень... что и досадно.
Вот то что написал

```
String str = "CompaniesTemp.comp1.Branches.bra1.TransportObjects.kamaz";
String str1 = null;
String str2 = null;
String pattern = "(Branches)\\.(.*?)\\.(.*?)\\.(.*?)\\.(.*?)+";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find())
{
    if(m.group(1).equals("Branches"))
    str1 = m.group(2);
    if(m.group(3).equals("Departments"))
    str2 = m.group(4);
}
```

Но оно не работает если в переменной `str` меняется путь.

Comment: Если у вас новый вопрос, вы можете его задать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и сослаться на этот вопрос, если они взаимосвязаны.

Comment: Да уж, тут пока дождешься подсказки я уже и сам разобрался))))Так что вопрос закрыт